# how the async function work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Let's say there are two async functions:

```
async function asyncCall() {
  for(var i=0;i<50000;i++){
     console.log('1');
  }
}
async function asyncCall2() {
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    console.log('2');
  }
}
```

And I call both functions:

```
asyncCall();
asyncCall2();
```

This is the output:

[image: Output]

`1` 50.000 times, then `2` one time.

Shouldn't the `2` be logged somewhere between 50.000 and 1 time?

Comment: No. `async` still doesn't allow you to run two functions **at the same time**. That would be *threading*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no threading in JavaScript. Since all your code is just executed in the one single thread of js, the output is expected.

Your misconception about `async` is quite common. You think that `async` implies some kind of "background work" but it is not! [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)ing involved in async! Within an async function you can just say "I did what I want to do, but know I need to wait.. maybe later I can carry on.. you can get the thread to do other stuff". But if other stuff started, than that other stuff is executed until it is done (or yields back the thread again).

To get your expected result you would need to yield back execution to the rest of the code from within the function - but still it is no threading and hence, if our awaited result arrived it is not processed until the currently running code is done.

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds(); // we will wait and during that time the single thread executing our code can do other stuff
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: 'resolved'
}

function fnCall2() {
  console.log('fn2');
  for(var i=0;i<500;i++) { // this will not be interrupted!
     console.log(i);
  }
}

asyncCall();
fnCall2();
```

The result of `asyncCall` will arrive after 2 seconds, but it does not mean it is processed immediately. If fn2 needs more time than the processing of the result is delayed. Try setting fn2 to iterate to `50000` - the `resolve` message will always be printed afterwards.